# Calling variables from one function to another in a class to in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, class

I have the main script file and a class file. In the class file, I have two functions (`funk` and `funk1`) and in the functions, I have several variables which I call from the main script.

However, if I have a variable in one function of the class, how can I use the same variable in another function of the class (it could be both as input or output)? Below is an example.

```matlab
classdef ga_clas
% The battery constraints
properties
 %Property1
end
methods (Static)
 function[a,b,c,d]=funk(f,g,h,i,j,k,l) 
  % The value of all input are from main script 
  for j=1:24
   g(j)=f(j)+k(j)
  end 
  % g is the variable in the class that can be used as output in another function, I'm not sure whether I'm using it correctly or not.
 end
 function [g, M, N]=funk1(t,y,u,i,f)
  % and If I have to use variables from the previous function (funk1) which could be input or output then can I use it here?
 end 
end
end
```

Comment: Each function has its own workspace, the variable `g` is cleared when `funk` returns (ends). You could return it as another output variable, and add it as an input to `funk1`. Or you could store it as a class property, but then the functions should not be static, and the class should derive from `handle` so that the function can update it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks you very much for the clarification. A quick question, is it possible that you could edit the above code as per your suggestions, it might be more useful and I accept your response as well :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways of doing this.

1: as Cris Luengo mentioned, you can return g. This would look something like this:

```
function[a,b,c,d,g]=funk(f,g,h,i,j,k,l) 
  for j=1:24
   g(j)=f(j)+k(j)
  end 
end
```

Then, when you call funk you would do:

```
main
%other code
[a, b, c, d, g] = ga_class(f, g, h, i, j, k, l)
```

2: set g as a property of ga_class:

```
properties
  g = [] %i don't know what type g is could be assigned as 0 or whatever it's type is
end
methods (Static)
 function[a,b,c,d]=funk(self, f,g,h,i,j,k,l) 
%self being passed in would be an instance of ga_class
  for j=1:24
   g(j)=f(j)+k(j)
  end 
  self.g = g %this assigns it into this method's properties
 end
```

Then, later you can call:
`ga_class.g`

You most likely want the first way, but it is possible to do it the second way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, a slight question is before 2nd function (funk1), should I use  " main and  [a, b, c, d, g] = ga_class(f, g, h, i, j, k, l)" and then after that I can use the variables (inputs or outputs) in the 2nd function (funk1), did I understand it well?